# How to directly use PKCS#12 file in ODP.NET?

Tags: odp.net, odp.net-managed, oracle-wallet

I'm trying to use the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 21.12.0 to connect to Oracle database. When configuring the TLS/SSL, it looks like that the ODP.NET only support setting the wallet location to one that has auto-login enabled.

My question is if ODP.NET could directly uses PKCS#12 wallet as I was only provided with the p12 file and doesn't have the sso file. If this is not supported, what the suggestions for handling this scenario?

Comment: Did you recently ask this question on the Oracle Forums? If not, please take a look at this link and let me know if it solves your problem: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/odpnt/featConnecting.html#GUID-0DF481DD-2BBE-4746-936C-1AF7830423F2